# jquery - clicking vs hitting enter on form gives different results - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a simple form on my page:

```
<form id="add_item_form" role="form">
  <input type="text" name="newitem" value="" id="new-item-input"/>
  <button type="button" id="new-item-button">go</button>
</form>
```

I have some JavaScript that is meant to capture either a button click or the user hitting ENTER from the text input.  The idea is that ENTER keyup event is captured and then then the button is clicked programatically.  When the button is clicked, an ajax post event should take place.  Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  console.log('start');

  // give the focus to the text input
  $("#new-item-input").focus();

  // if the user hits enter in the text input, click the button
  $("#new-item-input").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
      $("#new-item-button").click();
    }
  });

  // the callback function that is run if ajax succeeds
  var new_item_ajax_success = function(result) {
    console.log('success');
    $("#new-item-input").focus();
  }

  // the function that is run when the button is clicked
  var new_item_button_clicked = function() {
    console.log('new item button clicked!');
    $.post('/add_item/', {});
  }

  // add the function to the button
  $('#new-item-button').click(new_item_button_clicked);

  console.log('end');
});
```

My expectation is that the behavior should be identical whether the user hits ENTER or clicks the button.  However, that is not what happens.  When the user hits ENTER, the console log is as follows:

```
new item button clicked!
start
end
```

Also, my server log records a GET request.  The `start` and `end` in the console log indicate that the page is being reloaded, I think.

When the user clicks the button, the console log is as follows:

```
new item button clicked!
POST http://localhost:8000/add_item/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)
```

Also, my server log records a POST request.  (The 403 error is expected.)

My question: why am I not getting the expected behavior of a POST request in both cases?

Comment: You can handle *hitting* event using `key down` or `key press` events

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it is clear that, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, i.e., a key with a `keyCode == 13`, the below code gets executed:

```
// if the user hits enter in the text input, click the button
$("#new-item-input").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#new-item-button").click();
  }
});
```

At the same time, when you click the button, there's another code getting executed.

```
var new_item_button_clicked = function() {
  console.log('new item button clicked!');
  $.post('/add_item/', {});
}
```

Many browsers like Internet Explorer, do not follow proxy events like what is written below:

```
$("#new-item-button").click();
```

So, you might find that there's a difference between clicking and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I guess this should be the reason. Others, please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 $('#new-item-button').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
           $('#new-item-button').trigger('click');
    }
  });
```